# Usage of the word "refuse"

Tags: word-usage

I have a question regarding the proper usage of the word "refuse"

Let's say someone made a request to me, and my desire is to grant the request to the person. However let's assume that I am unable to grant the request despite my desire because the request entails something that is impossible for me to do. So if I say to this person, "sorry, I can't grant your request although I wish that I can do it for you", am I "refusing" to grant the request? or is there a better way to put it?

Comment: You could possibly say *Sorry, I'm afraid I have to refuse because...*. But in the circumstances you describe it would undoubtedly be better to avoid the word *refuse* altogether.

Comment: You need to show why standard and readily available references don't answer your question.

Comment: The alien arrived by rocket.  He refused to leave.

Answer (score 3):

[To refuse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/refused) means :

> - To indicate unwillingness (to do something): refused to leave.(AHD)

You are not refusing to do what you are being asked, you are just **unable/ not in a position to do it** ( for reasons that , presumably, do not depend on you)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more graceful if you *decline* the request, and *deny* and even *recuse* are possible. But if you say "I am unable to do that (at present)", it carries more of a connotation of regretful inability than outright refusal. Of course, for just this reason it is often used by those who are in fact refusing; if you want to make your position absolutely clear you would have to say "Whatever I would prefer, I cannot do that because..." and explain the reason, which may be of no ionterest to your listener.